# what's the difference between putting all codes inside the "window.onload" and putting only the function name inside the "window.onload"?

Tags: javascript

what's the difference between putting all codes inside the window.onload=function(){}; and putting only the function name inside the window.onload=function(){};?

putting all codes inside the window.onload:

```
window.onload=function() {
   function(){
       // do something here
   }
};
```

putting only the function name inside the window.onload:

```
function foo() {
   //do something here
}

window.onload=function() {
   foo();
};
```

what's the difference? or is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare it inside the `window.onload`, you only be able to use it when `window.onload` fires, not before. If you need to use the function before than hole document is loaded, you can't. Otherwise, if you write the function outside, you only call it when the event fires, but you can use it as soon as be defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar!

In the first case you declared a function only when `window.onload` is fired.

In the second case you declared a "globally" function accessible from `window.onload` event

See this plunker demo: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5WdwFKu3uNWc8ImtjG3W)

Comment: I thought that there's difference or something that this one is fast loading process than that one or something that this is faster and easier to read than that. because i learned from coders/programmers on javascript uses the only the function name nested inside the window.onload function.

Comment: Depends on what you need and what you do. In first case you can access only in the event.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case all your code in centralized in a anonymous function ,which is good since you aren't polluting the global namescpace.

In the second case , `foo` will be available globally in your js ,which could cause a clash if you or someone using your js file redefines `foo`

Answer (score 0):

```
First thing , You can't declare function inside function . As you first did ,  
You can write some query inside function.  But if you want use your query again 
and again then you have to declare a function and you will put your query. 
Then you will call that function from other function inside the same page.
```